# Why doesn't keto enol tautomerism take place in acid derivatives?

Tags: organic-chemistry, tautomer

Why does keto enol tautomerism take place only in ketones and aldehydes? Why doesn't it take place in carboxylic acids, esters, amides, anhydrides and acid chlorides?

Comment: Well, it does occur with acyl chlorides [https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040403901984953] and acyl bromides [https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Carboxylic_Acids/Reactivity_of_Carboxylic_Acids/Hell-Volhard-Zelinskii_Reaction].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't it take place in carboxylic acids, esters, amides, anhydrides and acid chlorides?

It does take place in acid derivatives as well.Acid chlorides and esters exhibit enolisation to a decent extent.However, the enol content is lesser than that in carbonyls due to cross-conjugation.

You could expect higher enol content in the following cases:

1.If there is an active methylene group ( or any other acidic $\ce{C-H}$ bond )

2.Extended conjugation in the enol form

3.Attainment of aromaticity after enolisation

4.Any intramolecular hydrogen bonding possibility in the enol form

Comment: Would amount of enol form be in the order acid chloride >anhydride>ester>carboxylic acid>amide based on +M and -I effect?

Comment: Yes, expected to be.However, I have seen tautomerisation in acid chlorides and esters only!.Generally, the enol content of others that follow esters in the order you have given is very less (< 0.001%) and hence tautomerisation can be neglected